# windows backslash in python os.path

Tags: python

I have hopes of making a batch file rename script in Python3.  To that end I have-

```
import os
filePath = "F:/tryit"
fileName = "/dummy1.txt"
newFileName = "/dummy2.txt"
oldName = filePath+fileName
newName = filePath + newFileName 
print(oldName)
print(os.path.normpath(oldName))
print(newName)
print(os.path.normpath(newName))
os.rename( os.path.normpath(oldName), os.path.normpath(newName))}
```

The print statements show the backslashes turned around appropriately but I get the error message-
 The system cannot find the file specified: `'F:\\tryit\\dummy1.txt'` -> `'F:\\tryit\\dummy2.txt'`

Where did the double backslashes come from and how can I get rid of them?
I have tried r"  for raw, and any number of consecutive backslashes to no avail.

Comment: this is just a console display of your string, the real string doesn't have the double \. You can check that by printing it to a txt file. Then check if your file actually exists...

Comment: You are exactly right. Guess the fact that the message was in red was a clue to its origin as a console display.  Thanks